# reshaping pandas data frame- Unique row error

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a data frame as the following;

[image]

I am trying to use the reshape function from pandas package and it keep giving me the error that

**" the id variables need to uniquely identify each row".**
[image]

This is my code to reshape:

link to the data: https://pastebin.com/GzujhX3d

```
GG_long=pd.wide_to_long(data_GG,stubnames='time_',i=['Customer', 'date'], j='Cons')
```

**The combination of 'Customer' and 'Date' is a unique row** within my data, so I don't understand why it throws me this error and how I can fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you please post your dataframe as code not an image for testing

Comment: @Kenan i added link to the data

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

I could identify the issue. the error was due to two things- first the name of the columns having ":" in them and second the format of the date- for some reason it doesn't like dd-mm-yy, instead it works with dd/mm/yy.